# Не полностью использует процессор

Tags: unity3d

Unity 5.4.0 по какой-то причине при запекании теней использует процессор на 1%, и процесс длится очень долго. Как с этим можно бороться? Скриншот окна "Lighting", вкладка Scene:

[image]

Сцена небольшая: коридор на 100-150 полигонов размером 12x2x1 метров.

Comment: Можете выложить скриншот `Lightmap settings` ? Вкладку `Scene`. И на сколько большая сцена? И версия юнити 5, а дальше какие цифры?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, скриншот: http://www.fayloobmennik.net/6796112

Comment: Unity 5.4.0, сцена небольшая: комната из 100-150 полигонов. Коридор размером 12x2x1 метров.

Comment: Всю информацию и скриншоты добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос через кнопку [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/605946/edit)

Comment: Странно. Можно попробовать Realtime Resolution увеличить до 8. Типа  для маленьких сцен можно 1–8 ставить. Почистить кэш Edit - Preferences - GI Cache  и попробовать еще